# Sending json body in a post message from android phone

Tags: android, json, rest, http-post

Hey I am looking to send this 
{
    "Longitude" : "123.123",
    "Lattitude" : "55.55"
} to my site with no other requirements from an android phone with volley. the methods dont seem to be working. can any one help me

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please add code snippets and post the stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question, you need to send two params to your site

this is sample code of volley to send POST data with params

```
public void PostToServer(String URL, final HashMap Params) {
    try {

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(networkContext);
        StringRequest strreq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String Response) {
                        try {
                           //your server response
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){@Override
        public Map<String, String> getParams(){
            return Params;
        }
        };

        queue.add(strreq);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And call this function like this

```
HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("Longitude", "12.123");
                params.put("Lattitude", "12.145");
               PostToServer("http://example.com/send.php", params);
```